# Rails & rspec load time not improved by spork

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rspec, spork

I've followed the installation instructions for spork-rails

I couldn't get `bundle exec spork` to run and got the error

```
/opt/local/bin/spork:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/bin/spork (LoadError)
from /opt/local/bin/spork:23:in `<main>'
```

I am in /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/bin/spork 's group and its permissions are 711.

Running `sudo bundle exec spork` works but when I then run `bundle exec rspec spec` it still takes 8+ seconds to load

I'm running:
ruby 1.9.3
rails 3.2.3
spork 1.0.0rc3
spork-rails 3.2.0
rspec 2.10.1
OSX 10.7.4
Installed with macports

**UPDATE** I've uninstalled macports ruby and reinstalled with rvm

This is allowing me todo `bundle exec sport` without sudo, but `bundle exec rspec spec` is still taking +8s to run

Comment: did you install it with sudo bundle install (you should never do that) ?

Comment: No but `bundle install` does ask me for my sudo password, is that as bad?

Comment: @msaspence Yes. You shouldn't ever need to use `sudo` for gem-related commands if you're using RVM or rbenv.

Comment: since uninstalling macports ruby and ruby gem and reinstalling with rvm I haven't, however rspec still not connecting to spork

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you run rspec you need to pass in the argument "--drb"
*rspec --drb spec/*

Answer (score 3):

You could also take a look at [spin](https://github.com/jstorimer/spin/), which does the same but is **a lot** easier to setup and less intrusive.

Comment: Spin is a lot easier, from 8s to 3s epic,   
I wont mark as the answer unless anybody else can offer any insight   in to the original question, but this has defiantly done the job for me

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the YaBoyQuy's answer you can add the `--drb` option in your `.rspec` and forget it. Here the content of my `.rspec` file:

```
--drb
--colour
--order=random
```

(Note I've added the `--order=rand` option that make rspec run tests in random order which is a good thing because your tests should not depend on each other)

Comment: --order=rand is a cool little tip I didn't know about, are there any negative side affects like a performance hit?

Comment: @msaspence from what I've seen (the time command) there is no difference, or at least not so much to be noticed. BTW it's a best practice to run the tests in random order because if they fail in "strange" ways or just sometimes (and other times passs) it means they depends on other tests and you should write them better.